# Custom MySQL query to pull out Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, mysql

I'm trying to modify the [My Wish List plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gd-mylist/) so that I can retrieve some custom fields (I'm using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to create my custom fields in the admin end).

The plugin uses the custom query below to pull out specific data, but I want to retrieve each post's custom fields as well in that loop. I'm pretty clueless when it comes to MySQL, but I'm assuming I need to add a line to `SELECT` like this to the query to be able to retrieve custom fields as well right?:

```
b.post_meta AS posts_meta,
```

**Here's the plugin's MySQL query in full:**

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT
                b.ID AS posts_id,
                b.post_title AS posts_title,
                b.post_content AS posts_content,
                b.post_date AS posts_date,
                c.ID AS authors_id,
                c.display_name AS authors_name
            FROM '.$var_setting['table'].' a
            LEFT JOIN '.$var_setting['table_posts'].' b
            ON a.item_id = b.ID
            LEFT JOIN '.$var_setting['table_users']." c
            ON c.ID = b.post_author
            WHERE
                b.post_status = 'publish'
                AND a.user_id = %s
            ORDER BY b.post_title DESC",
            $user_id
    )
);
```

**And here's the foreach loop that the plugin uses to pull in the content to display:**

```
if ($posts != null) {
        if ($share_list == 'yes') {
            $html = '';
            $html = file_get_contents($templates_html['box_list_share'].$locale);
            $permalink = get_permalink();
            if (strpos($permalink, '?') !== false) {
                $html = str_replace('##pageID##', $permalink.'&', $html);
            } else {
                $html = str_replace('##pageID##', $permalink.'?', $html);
            }
            $html = str_replace('##userID##', $user_id, $html);

            echo($html);
        }

        if ($show_count == 'yes') {
            $html = '';
            $html = file_get_contents($templates_html['box_list_count'].$locale);
            $count = $wpdb->num_rows;
            $html = str_replace('##count##', $count, $html);

            echo($html);
        }

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $postId = $post->posts_id;
            $postDate = get_the_date('F j, Y', $postId);
            $postAuthorId = $post->authors_id;
            $postAuthorName = $post->authors_name;
            $postContent = $post->posts_content;
            $postImage = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($postId));
            $postTitle = $post->posts_title;
            $portTitleLang = extract_title($postTitle);
            $postUrl = get_permalink($postId);

            /* BEGIN : OSU EDIT */
            $postACF_sc =  get_post_meta($postId, 'sc_link'); /* trying to get a specific custom field for each post */
            /* END : OSU EDIT */

            $args = array(
                'styletarget' => 'mylist',
                'item_id' => $postId,
            );
            $html = '';
            $html = file_get_contents($templates_html['box_list'].$locale);
            $html = str_replace('##postUrl##', $postUrl, $html);

            /* BEGIN : OSU EDIT */
            $html = str_replace('##postACF_sc##', $postACF_sc, $html); /* These str_replace() are how the plugin lets you add things like ##postUrl## using its templating system to display the permalink via AJAX */
            /* END : OSU EDIT */

            $html = str_replace('##postImage##', $postImage, $html);
            if (strpos($postTitle, '<!--:') !== false || strpos($postTitle, '[:') !== false) { //means use mqtranlate or qtranlate-x
                    $html = str_replace('##postTitle##', $portTitleLang[$lang], $html);
            } else {
                $html = str_replace('##postTitle##', $postTitle, $html);
            }
            $html = str_replace('##postDate##', $postDate, $html);
            $html = str_replace('##postAuthorName##', $postAuthorName, $html);
            $html = str_replace('##postContent##', $postContent, $html);
            $html = str_replace('##postBtn##', gd_show_mylist_btn($args), $html);

            echo($html);
        }
    } else {
        $html = file_get_contents($templates_html['box_list_empty'].$locale);
        echo($html);
    }
```

Comment: Are you changing the My Wish List plugin file(s), or are you taking a copy of its code and using it in your own theme/plugin?

Comment: I'm literally editing the plugin file directly. I know it's bad practice, but hopefully it will be a simple edit to do and I'm leaving comments where I've edited the files. Will do my best to integrate my changes into updates to the plugin!

Comment: We would need to see more code i.e. what the plugin subsequently does with `$posts`

Comment: Ok, I'll update the original post to show the foreach loop that is used to display content, one sec...

Comment: That's updated now - I've added comments with 'OSU EDIT' so you can see what I'm trying to do and where I've modified the plugin code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, I can't see any need to modify the query - I think you're missing [the third argument in your `get_post_meta call`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

```
$postACF_sc =  get_post_meta($postId, 'sc_link', true /* $single */);
```

You might also want to add this snippet just before the `foreach` to save multiple database queries:

```
update_postmeta_cache( wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'posts_id' ) );
```

Comment: Perfect! Looks like the third argument sorted it - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To get the custom fields for a post you would need to add something like the following:

```
d.meta_value (in the select clause)

LEFT JOIN '.$var_setting['table_postmeta'].' d
        ON d.post_id = b.ID (in the from clause)
```

I don't know the plugin so I can't promise it will work but this is how you join to the postmeta table to pull the custom fields.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, so should it look like this? https://gist.github.com/osuosu/e4f4a722f9652e51976b0e337f8302f2

Comment: Looks good. Give it a try :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it breaks the code... but really appreciate your help! Looks like I got things sorted with TheDeadMedic's suggestion :)